# Getting a cookie after a successful login?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, cookies, cas

So I have an Angular App that has user login and authentication. When they login they go to a separate url and service, that's not a part of the angular template (not my choice, not my design, don't have freedom to change it).

So we have our app url at https://my.app.com/appname

And the login url (Which redirects to another URL that has the Spring CAS stuff)

https://my.app.com:8082/api/applications/appname/user/login

Which redirects to

https://yours.app.com/CAS/login.

After a successful login, we go back to the original app page.

However, I need to somehow get the Cookie that has the username of the user logging in to the app.

That cookie is a response cookie tied to https://my.app.com:8082/api/applications/appname/user/login

but not the main url of the app.

So how do I retrieve this cookie, preferably using ngCookie?

For reference here's the backend code that handles this.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/login", headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody HttpServletResponse login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // toLog(Level.INFO, "Logging user in.");
    String referingURL = request.getHeader("referer");
    _LOG.debug("Referer: " + referingURL);
    try {
        String user = "123456789";
        user = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUsername();
        Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("USERNAME", user);
        userCookie.setSecure(true);
        response.addCookie(userCookie);
        response.sendRedirect(referingURL);
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // toLog(Level.ERROR, "Error logging user in", e);
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(e);
    }
}
```

Where that Cookie userCookie line is.. that's the cookie I want to get.

In even simpler terms.

The url https://my.app.com:8082/api/applications/appname/user/login

Has a response Cookie with a key called USERNAME, with the value of username I want.

The app lives on https://my.app.com/appname, and I need to access the previously mentioned cookie.

Answer (score 1):

CAS does not set a cookie with the user login. It will set a cookie for your SSO session called a Ticket Granting Cookie (TGC). This token does not provide any information on the logged user.

To retrieve the identity of the user logged you have to validate a Service Ticket. This ticket is appended to the url of your service when CAS/login redirect you back to you application. Then a CAS Client must validate that ticket against CAS/serviceValidate. That client should be in your backend and the username set in the session. Up to you to send it to your frontend the way you want.

Comment: Please see the above edit where I show where the cookie is create in Java.

Comment: Ok so you are already authenticated and just set another cookie with the username. You will have set the path of your cookie in the backend method to the root of your application with setPath("/") so it will be available on all the paths.